# Using Catalan Numbers for an example

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

Situation:

We want to build a wall. The lowest level of this wall consists of 9 stones. Every stone ( except the stones of the lowest level) has to be on the middle of two other stones. Moreover we have no gaps regarding the lowest level. Question: how many options do we have for a wall like this?

my idea\work:

I made a picture of this situation.[image]

I think this has to do with the Catalan numbers $C_n$. Maybe "up" is like opening a parantheses and " going right" is like closing a parantheses? I think the solution is $C_9$. Am I right? If I'm Right: Can you please help me to improve my attempt. It is a bit messy and not detailed.

*** Second Explanation ***
Maybe just going up is to open a parantheses and going down again is like Closing a parantheses. But I'm not sure if $C_9$ is correct. I mean in my picture Im going only 6 times up and 6 times down.

Comment: Going right is "encoded" as a down move followed by an up move.  Counting this way, you get 6+3=9 up moves and 6+3=9 down moves.  I've gone from believing it's not the Catalan numbers to believing you're right in that it's $C_9$

Comment: @drhab - I double counted one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems correct to me.

If we give the utmost left brick the coördinates $(0,0),(0,1),(2,0),(2,1)$.

Then starting at $(0,0)$ add arrow $\nearrow$ to your picture, going from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$.

Under the criterium that the arrows must be pictured *on the wall* repeat this, and if such arrow is not possible then add arrow $\searrow$ (which can be done on the wall).

Then a path comes in sight starting at $(0,0)$ and ending at $(18,0)$ where the cornerpoints have nonnegative coördinates.

There are $C_9$ of such paths.